# How to make two query to redis from node.js using promise from when.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis, promise

I have a node.js with modules redis and when.js . How to create  two query to redis using promise from when.js and then run another function. Now i make it without promise from when.js .

```
redisClient.get("value_1", function (err, data_1) {
  redisClient.get("value_2", function (err, data_2) {
    another_function(data1, data2);
  });
});
```

Help me please. Thanks for an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest using [Bluebird](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird) (instead of when.js) and its [promisification](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#promisification) feature to promisify `redisClient.get` calls.

Then you can have something like:

```
var Promise = require("bluebird");
Promise.promisifyAll(require("redis"));
var join = Promise.join;

join(redisClient.getAsync("value_1"), redisClient.getAsync("value_2"), 
    function(data1, data2) {
      another_function(data1, data2);
    });
```

Comment: Yea !) Thanks. I was looking for a good module for a promise and when.js is first what i found. But now i will use bluebird.

Comment: @krl why have you used join in here?